# Ant configurations - Meaning of debuglevel attributes var lines and source

Tags: ant, javac

Can you please explain the meaning of debug level attributes `var` , `lines` and `source` in Apache Ant. It is clear that this help to generate all debugging information helping the attribute `debug=true`.

1. What is the purpose of defining `debuglevel="lines,vars,source"`. Is this restricting the debug information?
2. What is the role if each value 1. `lines` 2. `vars` 3. `source` ?
3. Should I need to turn on `debug` to make this attribute works ?

The specification says:

> Keyword list to be appended to the -g command-line switch. This will be ignored by all implementations except modern, classic(ver >= 1.2) and jikes. Legal values are none or a comma-separated list of the following keywords: lines, vars, and source. If debuglevel is not specified, by default, nothing will be appended to -g. If debug is not turned on, this attribute will be ignored.

Answer (score 7):

In Ant, you must use both `debug=true` and `debuglevel=...` to get debugging to work. The `lines,vars,source` basically links Java code back to the line number, the variable name in the source, and the name of the source itself. This way, tools like Findbugs and point back to the line in the source code even though they work on the classfile.

There's no difference between running a Java app that has this information embedded vs. not being embedded. In C, it ***use to*** make a difference. C debug information took up more room in the binary and C could be slower to execute because of the debug information embedded in the binary. This is not true in the Java world where the code is coded to an *intermediate* file that's interpreted by a Java Realtime Environment.

I have yet seen a Java shop that doesn't compile with this information embedded in the classfiles. Java is a runtime code, and the debugging information embedded in the code doesn't slow it down. JIT compiling greatly speeds things up, and that ignores the embedded debugging information. Besides, if speed is really that important, you shouldn't be using Java (Sorry. Truth hurts.<sup>1</sup>)

My recommendation is to go ahead and compile with debug on, and debuglevel set to `lines,vars,source`. It's probably more important to have this debugging information embedded than whatever possible microscopic speed improvement you'll see by removing it.

---

<sup>1.</sup> Before the nasty comments: I mainly working in the Java environment. There are many reasons why you may want to use Java over C or C++, but speed isn't one of them.

However, there's a difference between programming in 1980 when you had a 8085 chip running a full blazing 8 bits at 3MHz and now where even the junkiest system runs quad core 64bit chips running in the GHz realm. It's more important to write easy to maintain and debug programs than *efficient* programs.

Comment: Your first sentence ("In Ant, you must use both debug=true and debuglevel=... to get debugging to work.") is wrong, actually if you leave out the debuglevel option, you get the same result as with "lines,vars,source" - all the possible debug info.

Comment: According to the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/), "If debuglevel is not specified, by default, nothing will be appended to `-g`." Thus, it really depends upon the version of `javac` being executed. Looking at the documentation for [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html), not specifying `debuglevel` is the same as `debuglevel="lines,vars"`. When I first started working with Ant, I was using Java 1.4 which may not have had a default value for `debuglevel`. I'll have to check.

Comment: I agree about the ant manual, but actually on the javac page linked by you it does not say that -g is the same as -glines,vars, it says -g "Generate **all** debugging information", that is -g:lines,vars,source. To verify this, I compiled a file with Java 7 javac, and it created exactly the same binary class file with -g as with -g:lines,vars,source. Also see this: http://marxsoftware.blogspot.hu/2011/02/determining-level-of-java-debug-in.html

Comment: I saw _By default, only line number and source file information is generated._, and assumed that's what `-g` does by default. However, it could be interpreted that not putting `-g` generates line numbers and source file info. According to the Ant manual, setting `debug` to `false` is like setting `-g:none`.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are getting confused by compile Java code from the command line vs using the [Ant  task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html).

The -g is a command line flag to passed to javac to compile the source files.   For more information you can run `javac -help` and get the following output.   In our build files - we just set `debug=on` inside the `<javac>` task to handle requesting the correct debugging information be written out.

```
    Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    where possible options include:
    -g                         Generate all debugging info
    -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
    -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
    -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
    -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
    -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
    -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
    -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files and annotation processors
    -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
    -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
    -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
    -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
    -proc:{none,only}          Control whether annotation processing and/or compilation is done.
    -processor <class1>[,<class2>,<class3>...] Names of the annotation processors to run; bypasses default discovery process
    -processorpath <path>      Specify where to find annotation processors
    -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
    -s <directory>             Specify where to place generated source files
    -implicit:{none,class}     Specify whether or not to generate class files for implicitly referenced files
    -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
    -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
    -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
    -version                   Version information
    -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
    -Akey[=value]              Options to pass to annotation processors
    -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
    -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
    -Werror                    Terminate compilation if warnings occur
    @<filename>                Read options and filenames from file
```